# Dynamic sidebar menu RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a problem with my dashboard.
I want create a dynamic sidebar menu, but by default, Menu item don't work. The user has to clic on it to show it. I have find an example on this problem 
https://github.com/rstudio/shinydashboard/issues/71
but the solution don't work.
If you have ideas... thank you in advance

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(id="mytabs",
      menuItem("Menu item", tabName="dashboard", icon = icon("calendar"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Rather than using the renderMenu functions, it's much easier to just use htmlOutput, and renderUI, then you can put whatever you want in there.

Comment: Given code worked for me

Comment: @Shape Yes but I have the same problem :

`ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderUI({
    sidebarMenu(id="mytabs",
                menuItem("Menu item", tabName="dashboard", icon = icon("calendar")))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)`

Comment: @kppatel-patel Yes it work but it's not what I want, the user doesnt click on Menu item but move directly to content Menu item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution using `updateTabItems`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id="mytabs",
      sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "dashboard", h2("Dashboard tab content"))
  ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
              menuItem("Menu item", tabName="dashboard", icon = icon("calendar"))
    )
  })
  isolate({updateTabItems(session, "mytabs", "dashboard")})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To extend to dynamic menu you can see this exemple.
[R shinydashboard dynamic menu selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742932/r-shinydashboard-dynamic-menu-selection/36913826#36913826)

Edit : I think the `isolate` is not needed but I like to put it in a way to improve the reading of the code

Comment: Great happy to help!