# shinyauthr Fails To Open First Tab Item In UI

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyauthr

I have a shiny app where I am using the awesome shinyauthr package. However, I am having one issue. There is a blank page once I sign in.

Right now I have 5 tabs in my sidebar. In my UI I access the information in each sidebar with tabItems().

shinyauthr does not automatically open up the tab. Instead I have to open a new tab and then go back to the original tab to display the data.

Here is the graphical issue before I show the code.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my code. I think I have to add some java.script somewhere that says, open the first tab item after authentication.

The full code is 700 lines so I will just post a snippet of the code. If you would like me to show all my code, I will be happy to post it.

***I have edited the code to give a reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(glue)
library(shinyauthr)

user_base <- data_frame(
    user = c("user1", "user2"),
    password = c("pass1", "pass2"), 
    password_hash = sapply(c("pass1", "pass2"), sodium::password_store), 
    permissions = c("admin", "standard"),
    name = c("User One", "User Two")
)

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "shinyauthr",
                    tags$li(class = "dropdown", style = "padding: 8px;",
                            shinyauthr::logoutUI("logout")),
                    tags$li(class = "dropdown", 
                            tags$a(icon("github"), 
                                   href = "https://github.com/paulc91/shinyauthr",
                                   title = "See the code on github"))
    ),

    dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE, 
                     sidebarMenu(
                         menuItem("dash", tabName = "dash"),
                         menuItem("hey", tabName = "hey")
                     )
    ),

    dashboardBody(
        shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
        tags$head(tags$style(".table{margin: 0 auto;}"),
                  tags$script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.16/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js",
                              type="text/javascript"),
                  includeScript("returnClick.js")
        ),
        shinyauthr::loginUI("login"),
        uiOutput("user_table"),

        uiOutput("testUI"),
        HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    credentials <- callModule(shinyauthr::login, "login", 
                              data = user_base,
                              user_col = user,
                              pwd_col = password_hash,
                              sodium_hashed = TRUE,
                              log_out = reactive(logout_init()))

    logout_init <- callModule(shinyauthr::logout, "logout", reactive(credentials()$user_auth))

    observe({
        if(credentials()$user_auth) {
            shinyjs::removeClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
        } else {
            shinyjs::addClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse")
        }
    })

    output$user_table <- renderUI({
        # only show pre-login
        if(credentials()$user_auth) return(NULL)

        tagList(
            tags$p("test the different outputs from the sample logins below 
             as well as an invalid login attempt.", class = "text-center"),

            renderTable({user_base[, -3]})
        )
    })

    user_info <- reactive({credentials()$info})

    user_data <- reactive({
        req(credentials()$user_auth)

        if (user_info()$permissions == "admin") {
            dplyr::starwars[,1:10]
        } else if (user_info()$permissions == "standard") {
            dplyr::storms[,1:11]
        }

    })

    output$welcome <- renderText({
        req(credentials()$user_auth)

        glue("Welcome {user_info()$name}")
    })
    x = as.data.frame(rnorm(100))

    output$testUI <- renderUI({
        req(credentials()$user_auth)
     tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "dash",
        fluidRow(
            column(
                width = 12,
                tags$h2(glue("Your permission level is: {user_info()$permissions}. 
                     Your data is: {ifelse(user_info()$permissions == 'admin', 'Starwars', 'Storms')}.")),
                box(width = NULL, status = "primary",
                    title = ifelse(user_info()$permissions == 'admin', "Starwars Data", "Storms Data"),
                    DT::renderDT(user_data(), options = list(scrollX = TRUE))
                )
            )
        )),
            tabItem(tabName = "hey",
                DT::renderDataTable(x)
            )
     )
    })

}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You have to create a .js file in the same folder called returnClick.js

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if ($("#login-password").is(":focus") && (event.keyCode == 13)) {
    $("#login-button").click();
  }
});
```

Comment: I guess your problem is not related to `shinyauthr`. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36742932/r-shinydashboard-dynamic-menu-selection/36913826#36913826)?

Comment: Thanks SBista, I have decided to use shinymanager instead. The package is a bit easier to use and it worked great.